# Deja Dup Always Says "Create My First Backup" After Restoring Instead of "Backup Now"

Tags: backup, deja-dup

When I restore a backup, the next time I try to make a backup, all of my backup settings are gone and Deja Dup only gives the options to "Create My First Backup", or to restore. But this isn't my first back up. After restoring I want to have the "Back Up Now" button, keeping the previous backup chain going as if nothing happened.

This is annoying because the initial backup takes forever, I have to select again which folders I want to be backed up/ignored, and I assume this fills my backup disk with redundant data.

What I would like to happen is:

1. Create My First Backup
2. Wipe my hard drive
3. Reinstall the OS and Deja Dup
4. Restore the backup
5. Change some files
6. Open Deja Dup to see "Last backup was two hours ago" and the "Backup Now" Button

Instead, in #5 Deja Dup always says "Create My First Backup" even though the rest of the system is identical to a *previous* backup.

I am running MX Linux, but I've encountered this behavior on Ubuntu, Mint, and Pop!_OS as well.